# PHP - return mysql rows in same order as called

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to use a SELECT query to select 3 rows, but I want them in the same order I call for them.  This is what I attempted to do:

```
$array = array("50", "23", "67");
$list = implode(",", $array);

foreach($db->query("SELECT * FROM champs WHERE id IN ($list) ORDER BY 
    DECODE(id, $array[0], 1, $array[1], 2, $array[2], 3)") as $row) {
    //Do stuff
}
```

however, I get:

`Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax`

is there a way to ensure it is always returned in the order I call it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`decode()` is an Oracle function, not a MySQL function.  You should use `case`, which works in both databases:

```
SELECT *
FROM champs
WHERE id IN ($list)
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN id = $array[0] THEN 1
               WHEN id = $array[1] THEN 2
               WHEN id = $array[2] THEN 3
          END);
```